# Terminal cursor in VSCode obscures the command I type so I can't fully see it

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, cursor

When I start to type a command in VSCode terminal, the cursor sort of multiplies and partly obscures the command, so I can't fully read it, as on this picture (it reads "git status"). Besides, if I try out different styles in the settings, the cursor won't change  - it remains the same.

VSCode 1.74.1/Mac OS High Sierra 10.13
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weWM4.png)

Changing fonts doesn't help. I tried to reinstall the app, but it's all the same.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I has finally found what the problem was - I switched "GPU Acceleration" in the terminal settings to Off and now it's all good. And that makes sense since very recently I started to have occasional problems with my GPU which is very old (from 2010), so it had affected the cursor and command line in VSCode.